# How to prevent UITableViewCell from appearing behind other cells, when animating the deletion of the cell?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uitableview

In my table view I have a bunch of cells that are 44.0 pt in height. I also have some cells that are 200.0 pt in height. When I try to delete the cell of with a height of 200.0 pt, I use the `UITableViewRowAnimationTop` animation style. The animation works, however because the 200.0 pt cell is higher than the 44.0 pt cell above it, you can see the 200.0 pt cell sliding past the 44.0 pt cell above it.

How can I prevent this cell from appearing behind the table and other cells as it is sliding up while being deleted?

P.S. I am using the grouped style table view so I can see this cell in the header space between sections as it slide up. I don't want that to happen.

Comment: Use a different animation style?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UITableViewRowAnimation) indeed says:

```
... the deleted row or rows slides out toward the top.
```

I've recently used `UITableViewRowAnimationFade` because of 'weird' shifting of rows with `UITableViewRowAnimationTop/Bottom`.